# How to describe a grafana dashboard displaying systemd units

Tags: grafana, prometheus, systemd

I have node_exporter running and want to create a grafana dashboard but I'm not sure what concepts to search the documentation for. I want to display a list of hosts with a list of systemd units whose status is represented by the labels "active", "inactive", or "failed", with the colors green, grey, and red.

- What are the concepts I should search for?
- How do I describe what I'm trying to do?

I keep finding ways to manage grafana or prometheus with systemd like [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/packaging/rpm/systemd/grafana-server.service) or I found an old dashboard without a code repository link [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1617)

This is a picture of what I'm trying to build:

[image]

This is an example of the kind of metrics I'm getting from node_exporter related to a given service, foo.service in this case:

```
vagrant@srv0:~$ curl -s localhost:9100/metrics | grep systemd | grep foo.servicenode_systemd_unit_state{name="foo.service",state="activating",type="simple"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="foo.service",state="active",type="simple"} 1
node_systemd_unit_state{name="foo.service",state="deactivating",type="simple"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="foo.service",state="failed",type="simple"} 0
node_systemd_unit_state{name="foo.service",state="inactive",type="simple"} 0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I managed to achieve something similar without plugins (Grafana v9.4.3):

- Set your query to system statuses whichever is equal to 1 at current time (you can add any number of services in the query):

```
node_systemd_unit_state{name=~"nginx.service|fail2ban.service|meilisearch.service|node_exporter.service|promtail.service",instance="$source"} == 1
```

- In query options, set format to `Table` and type to `Instant`.
- This will show a lot of columns that we don't need, so use field overrides to hide any columns that you don't need. I hidden everything except for `name` and `status`. I also added override for `name` column to change type to `auto` so it would keep default color.
- Use value mappings to add colors.

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Status Panel](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vonage-status-panel) plugin might help you achieve what you want. I'm using it (together with [Discrete](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/natel-discrete-panel), for alert history) to display the state of all services across each environment (prod, stage and test).

I have 2 template variables, `$environment` and `$service` and I'm repeating a row consisting of a discrete panel and multiple status panels for each `$environment` value. Within the row, I'm repeating the status panel for each value `$service`. On the status panel itself, the color depends on whether there are alerts firing (similar to your set of states) and I'm also listing some metrics, such as QPS and median latency.

Answer (score 1):

As your example indicates, the node exporter creates a unique time series for each combination of {name,state,instance} (and other fields.

With a recent version of Grafana (8.4), it is easy to accomplish something close to your goal using the "Table" panel type and filtering. To create a table of only failed jobs, use an "instant" query like `node_systemd_unit_state{state="failed"}`. Add a transform to filter by value to greater-than-or-equal to `1`, use field overrides to hide any columns you don't care about, and then set a "Cell display mode" override for the `state` column. This will result in a list of failed units.

To show all units, even those which are not failed, you would presumably need to do some other type of transform... maybe "group by" or "reduce"? I'm not sure.